# How can I compare button 'text' to each other in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, error-handling, tk-toolkit

I've been working on tic-tac-toe project while working on this project I face the problem and that is **How can I get `tkinter Button['text']` text value through loop?**

**Is it possible, if not so any other way?**

I'd try to compare but it doesn't work, also I looked at some documentation but I'd get any help.

[my code on github](https://github.com/Dalal0/Tic-Tac-Toe-GUI-game-with-Thread/blob/master/tic-tac-toe-GUI.py)

**I'd try:**

```
for i in range(1, 10):
     print(f'self.btn{i}[\'text\']')
```

**Return:**

```
self.btn1['text'] <<---- problem this result.
self.btn2['text'] 
self.btn3['text'] 
self.btn4['text'] 
self.btn5['text'] 
self.btn6['text'] 
self.btn7['text'] 
self.btn8['text'] 
self.btn9['text'] 

# Insted this I want Button values of tkinter
```

**How can I get these value in a better way?**

Comment: test for win - thats easier. test it for both. if no more fields can be taken and neither wins it is a tie.

Comment: keep buttons on list `btn[0]`, `btn[1]` and then you can use `for` loop to compare buttons with `x` and later with `o`

Comment: It's unclear what are you trying to check. Conditional expression is not correct and it's hard to understand what are you expecting from it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: if you use `!=` or `==` then don't use `in` . `if self.btn1['text'] == self.btn2['text'] == .... == 'x' :` or `if self.btn1['text'] != self.btn2['text'] != .... != '' :`

Comment: I want to check if `self.btn1['text'] != self.btn2['text'] != self.btn3['text']: ...........` but it return`'boolean` value

Comment: if you expect that it may have different value then `x`, `o` or `` (empty)then you would have to check every button separatelly `if (self.btn1['text'] not in ('x', 'o', '')) or (self.btn2['text'] not in ('x', 'o', ''))  or .... :`

Comment: ok,but it will long code.

Comment: yes it will be long. it would be shorter if you would keep buttons on list - and then you could use `for` loop for this.

Comment: please, see my code

Comment: Can you implement it in a code!

Comment: you can also use `set()` to get all values from buttons `set([btn1['text'], self.btn1['text'], ...])` and compare with `set(('x', 'o', ''))`

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: `set(('x', 'o', ''))` can be used to check if buttons don't have values different then `'x','o', ''`. Or you can compare with `set(['x'])` to check if all buttons have `'x'`.

Comment: `f'self.btn{i}[\'text\']' !=''` - string can't create variable or any other code. And `print()` is used to display text on screen, not to create variable or code. Better use list to keep buttons - and then you can use `for`-loop to create them and use them. `btn = []` and `bnt.append(Button(...))`

Comment: please, could you put `f'self.btn{i}[\'text\']' !=''` in code.

Comment: I'll understand in a better way.

Comment: please, just a few line of code.

Answer (score 0):

To check buttons you can't use string and `print()` - they can create only string and display it on screen.

You would have to use `for` loop like this

```
result = False

for btn in all_buttons:
    if btn['text'] == ' ':
        result = True
        break # there is no need to check rest

print("There are empty buttons:", result)
```

or

```
result = False

for btn in all_buttons:
    result = result or (btn['text'] == ' '):

print("There are empty buttons:", result)
```

(sometimes instead of `or` there may need `and` - all depend of what you try to check - `any` or `all`)

---

Or you can use `any()` or `all()`

```
result = any(btn['text'] == ' ' for btn in all_buttons)
print("There are empty buttons:", result)
```

You can use it also with `sum()` to count

```
result = sum(btn['text'] == 'X' for btn in all_buttons)
print("Number of buttons with X:", result)
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
root = tk.Tk()

all_buttons = []

for row in range(3):
    for col in range(3):
         #btn = tk.Button(root, text=str(row*3+col))
         btn = tk.Button(root, text=random.choice(['X', 'O', ' ']))
         all_buttons.append(btn)
         btn.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='news')

for btn in all_buttons:
    print('>', btn['text'], '<')

#---

result = sum(btn['text'] == 'X' for btn in all_buttons)
print("Number of buttons with X:", result)

result = sum(btn['text'] == 'O' for btn in all_buttons)
print("Number of buttons with O:", result)

result = sum(btn['text'] == ' ' for btn in all_buttons)
print("Number of empty buttons:", result)

print('---')

result = False
for btn in all_buttons:
    if btn['text'] == ' ':
        result = True
        break
print("There are empty buttons:", result)
print('---')

# the same using `any()` or `all()`    
result = any(btn['text'] == ' ' for btn in all_buttons)
print("Any button is empty:", result)
print("All buttons are used:", not result)
print('---')

result = all(btn['text'] != ' ' for btn in all_buttons)
print("Any button is empty:", not result)
print("All buttons are used:", result)
print('---')

result = all(btn['text'] == 'X' for btn in all_buttons)
print("Any button doesn't have X:", not result)
print("All buttons have X:", result)
print('---')

result = all(btn['text'] in ('O', 'X') for btn in all_buttons)
print("Any button doesn't have O or X:", not result)
print("All buttons have O or X:", result)
print('---')

rows = [
    all_buttons[0:3],
    all_buttons[3:6],
    all_buttons[6:9],
]    

for number, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    result = all(btn['text'] == 'X' for btn in row)
    print("Row", number, "has three X (X wins):", result)
print('---')

columns = [
    [all_buttons[0], all_buttons[3], all_buttons[6]],
    [all_buttons[1], all_buttons[4], all_buttons[7]],
    [all_buttons[2], all_buttons[5], all_buttons[8]],    
]

for number, col in enumerate(columns, 1):
    result = all(btn['text'] == 'X' for btn in col)
    print("Column", number, "has three X (X wins):", result)

tk.mainloop()
```